# Does modsecurity have a module for nginx or Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, nginx, mod-security

Does modsecurity have a module for nginx or Tomcat that work without Apache?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Mod-security has modules for nginx, IIS and java.

You can find it [here](http://www.modsecurity.org/projects/modsecurity/java/index.html)